# How to make an additional api call in the componentDidMount hook in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, react-native

ive been searching online but I couldnt find out what is the most proper way to make an additional api call to a different api. Currently, I have displayed country information that I got from the countries API. This api will return info such as country name, population, land area, languages, etc. The idea is I want to make a subsequent api call to the "unsplash" api, which would return the image(s) based on the keyword. THe keyword would be the this.props.match.params.name which is the name of the country I am receiving as props. Just wanted to know what is the best way and how to do two api calls in the componentDidMount hook. Please see below for code and picture. Am I doing the right thing in the componentDidMount?  Thanks!

I plan to display the photos below this section
[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import AOS from 'aos';

class CountryPage extends React.Component{

    state = {
        country: null,
        photos: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${this.props.match.params.name}`)
            .then(response=> {
                this.setState({
                    country: response.data[0]
                })
                console.log(this.state.country)
            })
            axios.get(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=${this.props.match.params.name}`)
            .then(response=> {
                this.setState({
                    photos: response.data[0]
                })
                console.log(this.state.photos)
            })
            AOS.init({
                duration: 1000
            });
    }


    render() {
        if(!this.state.country){
            return <p>Loading</p>
         }
        return(
            <div className="countryPageBack">
                <NavBar/>
                 <div className="container">
                     <div className="countryAndFlag animate__bounceIn">
                        <h1 className="countryPageTitle">{`${this.props.match.params.name} - (${this.state.country.nativeName})`}</h1>
                        <img className="countryPageFlag" src={this.state.country.flag}/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-left" className="countryBasics">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Basic Info</h3>
                        <div className="basicDesc">{`Located in ${this.state.country.region}, ${this.state.country.name} has a population of ${this.state.country.population} people`}</div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Currency: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.currencies[0].name} - {`${this.state.country.currencies[0].symbol}`}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Langauges Spoken: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.languages[0].name}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Capitols: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.capital}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-right" className="countryRegion">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Regional Info</h3>
                        <div className="propertyName">Region: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.region}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Subregion: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.subregion}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Timezones: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.timezones}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Area: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.area}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-left" className="countryOthers">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Other Info</h3>
                        <div className="propertyName">Calling Code: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.callingCodes}</span></div> 
                        <div className="propertyName">Country Code: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.alpha3Code}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Main Domain: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.topLevelDomain}</span></div>
                    </div>                           
            </div>
            <Footer/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CountryPage;
```

Comment: do the second api call inside of the then function of first api call.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez No, you can make 2 api calls, the second call does need the result of the fist.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have (other than being edited in an editor that doesn't know how to format code)?